# Why can't I load seqinr package in R?

Tags: r

I am learning R. I have install "seqinr package" successfully. But when I load the "seqinr" package, it is something wrong. Does anyone know how to resolve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahCCe.png)

I have tried to install package ade4，but it was shown like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVwiB.png)

Comment: install package `ade4` additionally.

Comment: If something like "there is no package called XXX" appears, then just install package XXX.

Comment: Thank you. But when I install package ade4, it told me "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lquadmath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ade4.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ade4’
* removing ‘/Users/user/Library/R/3.3/library/ade4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ade4’ had non-zero exit status".

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps the first part of your question.

For the `seqinr` package, I utilize the following code:

```
install.packages("seqinr") 
#https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seqinr/versions/4.2-8

library(seqinr)
```

It seems old school but I always put the install and call for the library embedded within the code. Also are you using R Studio or just R? I have been dabbling in this same library myself.

Comment: I always put the documentation code if available embedded in the code but hashtagged out as a comment. I find it just makes things a bit easier and cleaner. Especially if you ever have to share the code or pass on the project to someone else or leave the code for a while and come back to it.